# Minitest/Capybara/Devise login is not progressing past sign in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capybara, minitest

Following some information from this example: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/644-how-to-test-authentication-with-devise-capybara-minitest I have the test half running.  But the **click_on** method isn't submitting the form.  I've also tried **click_button 'Sign in'** and **page.execute_script("$('form').submit()")** without any luck.  Here' the test:

```
# test/integration/login_test.rb
require "test_helper"
require "minitest/rails/capybara"

class LoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!

  let(:user) { User.new(email: "example@blah.com", password: "password") }

  it "will login successfully" do
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'user_password', with: user.password
    click_on 'Sign in'
    current_path.must_equal dashboards_path
    page.must_include 'Signed in successfully'
  end
end
```

According to the **page.execute_script** method error it said **Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError Exception: Capybara::Driver::Base#execute_script** and after reading another question on here I added cappybara-webkit to try and have that work.  But no change with that.

The target form submit button is as follows:

```
<input class="btn btn-default" name="commit" value="Sign in" type="submit" />
```

The test error reads:

```
LoginTest
  test_0001_will login successfully                               FAIL (0.38s)
Minitest::Assertion:         Expected: "/dashboards"
          Actual: "/users/sign_in"
        test/integration/login_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:LoginTest>'
```

I've looked at the **page.html** with byebug and don't see any errors about invalid user or the like.  And I do see the value for email and password are set.  The page form just doesn't seem to be submitting.

Comment: I also get frustrated with testing as it's sometimes harder to test than to write working code.   Your test seems fine, though, in my test, with Devise and Minitest (though not the Minitest Spec) I encrypt my user password.  My owners.yml reads encrypted_password: <%= Devise.bcrypt(Owner, 'password') %>.   You are using Warden though.   So I guess I'd ask, are you SURE your controller action sends you to dashboards?

Comment: Yes I'm sure about the path.  It works with human interaction.  I'm not sure about the user stuff working with User.new.  But I'm not getting an invalid login... haven't gotten that far.  I'm just not having the form submit at all.  You can see the error says the page is still on "/users/sign_in".  Oh and Warden is what Devise is built on top of.

Comment: I personally don't use Warden.  I have a users (owners) in my case YML file.   My login method, then, is just like yours.   Given you click the button, which clearly exists, and you go no where, my assumption is you are actually getting an error that renders 'signon' again.  But you say you are inspecting the page right?   

For giggles, could you change your last three lines to these two?

    click_on 'Sign in'
    page.must_include 'Invalid email or password'

If that passes, you will know for sure you have an error.

Comment: You are correct.  The text did appear within the page.  So the question now remains of having the User work for this scenario.  I'm okay with Fixtures, but I don't want to use a Factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your last comment, you are failing to authenticate.   You want to avoid using a Factory.   So you want to use a Fixture, which is what I am also using.

In my case, here's my users.yml file (I call my users owners), which for me is in test/fixtures:

```
owner: 
# column: value
  first_name: 'Testy'
  last_name: 'McTesterton'
  email: 'test@test.com'
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise.bcrypt(Owner, 'password') %>
  admin: false
  confirmed_at: <%= Time.now %>
```

I have the Devise confirmable option selected so I have to feed it a confirmed_at for creation.   If you don't, you won't need that.   You will have to have a field for anything you have turned on though that would validate a user, which, hopefully, is no more than confirmed_at.   I can only help with confirmed at :).   The "admin" field is because I have an admin option.

This will create your user and you can log in with a the login method you have above.   I'm guessing it will work for you since it works for me.

Comment: I've updated my fixture accordingly.  Added `fixtures :all` to the test.  Set `let(:user) { users(:bob) }` since mine is written as bob rather than owner in the Users class.  And I still get the same error.  I'm going to write a test to make sure the fixture is valid: http://chriskottom.com/blog/2014/11/fixing-fixtures/

Comment: Okay my User is valid.  I'm still getting the same error I was initially.  Did you do anything specific to make the fixture Owner work with Devise?

Comment: I recently changed to minitest and this was easy for me as I just created that fixture, then used a login method that looks a lot like yours.   I didn't do anything special, no.   It didn't work, obviously, until I did confirmed_at and I had to encrypt the password as I showed.   But that was all the "special" there was.

Comment: Got it!  Had to change the test from entering user.password to just "password". Hat tip to Brandon Hilkert http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/managing-login-passwords-for-capybara-with-minitest-and-rails-fixtures/

Comment: I didn't think to post my login method, but, that's what I have too.  fill_in 'Password', with: "password".   Glad you got it.